# How to grep and replace with new names in r?

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
   res <- structure(list(date = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", 
  "2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-01-01"
  ), X0 = c(167L, 167L, 167L, 167L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L), X1 = c(185L, 
  185L, 185L, 185L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L), X3 = c(187L, 187L, 
  187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L), car = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
   "N", "N", "N", "N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want grep columns that contain certain strings, i tried

```
  te=c("ca|sf|at|kk")
  df=res[grep(te, names(res))]
```

It works fine. However, I want to replace the original names by the new ones. the output will be

```
    at    ca
 1 2000-01-01   A
```

This is just an example so colnames(df) <- c("at","ca")  will not work for my real data. i need it to be atomatique. replace what was grepped!

Comment: how to handle double colnames that can appear. Example: if your original columns are named `mydata` and `date`, they will both be renamed to `at`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `select` with `matches` to select those columns having a substring match with the 'te' pattern on the column names and then with `rename_all`, update the column names by extracting those substring based on 'te' pattern

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- res %>% 
          select(matches(te)) %>%
           rename_all(~ str_extract(., te))
```

-output

```
df 
#          at ca
#1 2000-01-01  A
#2 2000-01-01  A
#3 2000-01-01  A
#4 2000-01-01  A
#5 2001-01-01  N
#6 2001-01-01  N
#7 2001-01-01  N
#8 2001-01-01  N
```

Comment: how to avoid set names?

Comment: In my large data, i do not know what was grepped and this will not work for me.

Comment: @Tpellirn I assume that you want to make use of the same pattern vector 'te' for changing the column names.  In that case the `str_extract` should work